# Repeat a task in Python

Tags: python, operating-system, task, python-multithreading

I'm working on a simple shell program with Python, and I need to repeat a task (a simple `os.system` call ) every second.

Is it possible to make that, without interrupting the program flow ?
Like a multithreaded thing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### without threading

```py
import time

while True:
   time.sleep(1)
   do_stuff()
```

#### with threading

```py
import threading 
import time

def my_func():
  while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    do_stuff()

t1 = threading.Thread(target=my_func)  

t1.start()
```

Comment: Maybe `do_stuff` should be launched in its own thread.